# My Account ,My Orders display only after user is logged in mobile menu

Tags: php, magento

[image]Hi I am trying to display my orders, my payments option only after the user is login in mobile menu.Right now the megamenu is displaying twice.can any one fix it .Thanks in Advance.

```
<li>
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
?>
<a style="text-transform: none; border-bottom: 0px !important; background:#212121 !important;color:#fff;margin-top:-10px;margin-left: -18px;"
href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account/logout'; ?>">Logout</a>                   
<?php echo $menuHtml; ?> 
<a  class="extras" title="My Orders" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'sales/order/history'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></a>
 <a  class="extras" title="My Payments" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'md_partialpayment/summary/list/'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('My Payments') ?></a>
   <?php                            
    }else{
    ?>
    <a style="text-transform: none; border-bottom: 0px !important; background:#212121 !important;color:#fff;margin-top:-15px;margin-left: -18px;font-weight:300;"
                href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login </a> 
   <?php echo $menuHtml; ?>                     
   <?php
   }                                             
  ?>                                
 </li>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me this please thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by mega menu is displaying twice?

Comment: @sagar singh While Checking in mobile the menu is displaying twice actually my requirement is if the user is logged in it should display my orders and my payments else it should show only menu But here the menu is displaying twice.

Comment: first of all show where you have created session and try using <?php if(isset($_SESSION['any session value'])){ ?> MENU <?php } ?>

Comment: @SagarSingh i am not getting you what you are saying Can you please see the my code i have added image how it is dspalying.It is repeating the menu

Comment: i want to see the code where you have started the session

Comment: @SagarSingh actually i am new to magento started one week back by searching in google i have done this one Started the session at the begining <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ you can see in code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';


umask(0);

Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
<a style="text-transform: none; border-bottom: 0px !important; background:#212121 !important;color:#fff;margin-top:-10px;margin-left: -18px;"
href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account/logout'; ?>">Logout</a>  

<?php echo $menuHtml; ?> 
<a  class="extras" title="My Orders" href="<?php echo 
Mage::getBaseUrl().'sales/order/history'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('My 
Orders') ?></a>

    <a  class="extras" title="My Payments" href="<?php echo 
    Mage::getBaseUrl().'md_partialpayment/summary/list/'; ?>"><?php echo 
    $this->__('My Payments') ?></a> 


 <?php } else { ?>


 <a style="text-transform: none; border-bottom: 0px !important; background:#212121 !important;color:#fff;margin-top:-15px;margin-left: -18px;font-weight:300;"
            href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login </a> 
<?php echo $menuHtml; ?>  
THE CONTENT YOU WANT TO SHOW TO THOSE WHO ARE NOT LOGGED IN
<?php  }?>
```

Comment: where i need to add this one should i need to remove my code.I need to display menu as well as those two options i mean my orders and my payments

Comment: Can you please edit in my code which i have written if you dont mind

Comment: Right Now I'm Doing but in Future you have to do yourself